# Vetor não imprime corretamente

Tags: array, c++

> Crie um programa em C++. Peça que que um vetor de inteiros de 10 posições seja preenchido pelo usuário. Imprima a soma das componentes deste vetor.

Fiz o código abaixo mas ele não imprime os valores do vetores.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#define SIZE 10
/* run this program using the console pauser or add your own getch, system("pause") or input loop */

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    int valor[SIZE];
    int total, i, a;
    
//  a = sizeof(valor)/ sizeof(valor[0]);
    
    for (i = 1; i <= sizeof(valor)/ sizeof(valor[0]); i++)
    {
        cout<<"Digite o valor: ";
        cin>>valor[i];
    }
    
    for ( i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        cout<< valor[i];
    }
    
    
    for ( i = 1; i < 10; i++)
    {
        a = a + valor[i];
    }
    cout<< a;
    

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Qual o motivo de usar `sizeof(valor)/ sizeof(valor[0])` e não simplesmente `SIZE`? Se a variável `a` é um acumulador então você precisa inicializa-la com 0 e o índice `i` partir de 0, ou fazer `a = valor[0];` já que seu loop parte do índice 1.

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo

Comment: Como o @Maniero demonstrou, se você sabe o tamanho do array previamente, use isto. Pra começo, em **C++**, se você não sabe o que está fazendo (ou o porquê), na prática talvez deva estar usando **std::vector** ao invés de fazer arrays "na mão". Em **C**, a história é outra. C/C++, diferente de outras linguagens mainstream (PHP, Python, Ruby, etc...), você _deve_ saber o tamanho daquilo com o que está lidando, a menos que _precise_ ser dinâmico. Ou seja, se o seu array _não precisa ser dinâmico_, assuma que seu tamanho é estático e use isto a seu favor.

Answer (score 1):

O maior problema é que não está lendo a quantidade dados que acha que está. Está começando ler os dados e armazenando na posição 1 do *array*, sendo que o *array* começa na posição 0. Então já terá um lixo nessa posição e fará o resultado ser errado ou certo só por coincidência. Não entendi bem a conta que fez para ir até o final. Essa técnica é usada para outra coisa. Você já sabe o tamanho do *array*, porque não usar isso?

E por que não usar o vetor do C++ que é bem melhor? Não acho que deveria misturar C com C++.

Tem outras coisas que podem ser melhores, como ter um só laço para somar e imprimir. Organizando o código ficaria assim:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#define SIZE 10

int main() {
    int valor[SIZE];
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
        cout << "Digite o valor: ";
        cin >> valor[i];
    }
    int total = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
        cout << valor[i] << endl;
        total += valor[i];
    }
    cout << total;
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/HCEcGe). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/uxafgtaz-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/Algorithm/TotalInArray.cpp).